# Как мне логгировать действия модераторов на сайте через события? YII2

Tags: yii2, события

Я хочу логгировать все что делают модераторы на сайте, например когда они отредактировали новость, или удалили комментарий, создали тему форума и тд.
Скажите как мне это сделать, я хочу записывать кто сделал, что сделал, когда, где, во сколько.
Это делать через стандартные события? afterSave afterDelete ? расскажите поподробнее пожалуйста.
Как мне это видится, просто в нужный экшен вставляю код, типа Log($model);
и где-то это все записывается в базу

Answer (score 1):

Запустите миграцию для создания таблицы для логов

```
yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/log/migrations/
```

Добавьте в конфиг

```
'log' => [
    'targets' => [
        'access' => [
            'except' => ['application'],
            'prefix' => function ($message) {
                  $user = Yii::$app->has('user', true) ? Yii::$app->get('user') : null;
                  $userID = $user ? $user->getId(false) : '-';

                  return  $user;
            },
            'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
            'levels' => ['info'],
            'categories' => ['access'],
        ],
    ]
]
```

Ну и использование такое где нужно записать в базу

```
Yii::info(__METHOD__, 'access');
```

Comment: А в чем профит такого варианта?  Проще же через  afterSave, разве нет?

Comment: Использовать готовое или писать самому. Всё  равно в aftersafe вам прийдется добавить это тоже

Comment: 'log' в конфиге находится внутри компонентов? Класс компонента наследуется от DbTarget? Должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо, установил, в базу пишется,  
теперь я так понял надо в админке какой-то парсер message сделать?  Может есть готовые варианты.  А то там столько инфы что капец, гет, пост, сессион и тд  а мне надо  кто сделал, и что сделал.

или это делается в app\components\DBLog ?   можно тогда не большой примерчик как это делается?

Comment: Ну если вы используете так как у меня в примере то в app\components\DBLog вам придут сообщения в json формате. (Имя класса, имя метода, UserID) Если нужно обрабатывать то делайте что нужно вам с этими данными если просто складывать в базу, то оно и так будет строкой складывать их.

Comment: гет, пост, сессион и тд обычно содержатся в category=>application и level = 4. Если он пишется в лог, значит у вас либо указан еще какой-то target с Db либо можете внести категорию 'application' в игнор с помощью настройки except

Comment: У меня пишет по 2 записи, access и aplication  в конфиге строго как у вас.
Вот например в аксец пишет ["app\\modules\\post\\controllers\\BackendController","app\\modules\\post\\controllers\\BackendController::actionUpdate",1]   1 это юзер_ид
Получается в админке мне уже не сделать фильтрацию по юзеру, ведь нет отдельного поля user в базе.
2. Можете показать пример как у вас обрабатывается в DBLog message?

Comment: у меня в DBlog  ничего не меняется. делаю  
file_put_contents('log.txt', print_r($this->messages,1));  файл не создается

Comment: Вы же программист)) Можно и адаптировать под свои нужны. Писать в базу это одно, делать под это админку с фильтрами это второе. Упростил  код.

Comment: Вообще рекомендую изучить полную документацию по логам http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html#message-formatting
И логи можно смотреть в Debug панельке.

Comment: Спасибо, изучу, второй вариант почему-то не работает, в базу не пишется

Comment: А если создать в таблице лог еще одно поле для user_id  считаете это правильным решением?

Comment: По идее сломать это ничего не должно) Вообще стандартные логи существуют для того чтоб их можно было посмотреть стандартными средствами. Какие конечные у вас задачи, вы не описали. Поэтому что еще может понадобится неизвестно. Можете прыгнуть в yii\log\DbTarget и посмотреть что он делает. Всегда можно переопределить и написать то что вам нужно и как вам нужно. Главное тут наверное то что логи должны писаться один раз в базу после завершения запроса. А то если будут редиректы по экшенам или множественные записи это будет излишней нагрузкой на БД. Как получить данные вы уже знаете